# Addon for Particle System

Tags: add-on, system

Trying to use 'GRASS FREE' from http://3dwolf.weebly.com/grass.html . But i don't know where to put the python file, I have tried many but it's not working... I am on mac!

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin in Blender:

1) Open *Blender*.
2) Select *File > User Preferences* or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.
3) Go to the *addon* tab, and select *install from file* at the bottom of the panel.
4) Then simply find and select your *.py* file, and press **OK**.
5) Activate the addon you want, then select *Save user settings.*